# Take settings from nested local settings.json in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have got a local.settings.json like this

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "ServiceBusSettings": {
    "TransformedJson": {

      "ConnectionString": "connectionstring2"
    },
    "ServiceLogs": {
      "ConnectionString": "connectionstring3"
    }
  },
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

First of all is it acceptable to have nested JSON in Azure Functions Local.settings.json? I have that confusion because in Azure we dont have a json file instead we have environment variables as key val pair. (Please correct I am wrong)

If above json is acceptable, how can I get a specific key from the nested settings

For getting IsEncryped I can just use

```
 bool IsEncryped= configuration.GetValue<bool>("IsEncrypted")
```

Also in function parameter if I need to use value I can Just use

```
 %IsEncrypted%
```

In my case if I need to get the connection string under TransformedJson attribute and get its values and also I'd like to use that in my parameter with percentage notation.

Please suggest how can I accomplish that?